# When I update my app, does it need to be re-approved?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

If I have an app on the app store and I want to update it, does it need to go through the approval process again every time I update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, but the review times are much faster. I just submitted an update and it was reviewed and live within 5 days (counting the weekend).

Comment: Thats a huge bummer for anyone practicing agile development. I submitted my app, it hasn't even been approved yet and I already have two bug fixes to come out with